# How to erase an area delimited by a line segment and a block of colors?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, line, pixel

Given the picture below:

[image]

The position of A and B is known, the rest of the picture is just raw pixel data (only red and white pixels). What algorithm can I use to erase the part to the right of AB?

Comment: Two points don't make a polygon, they make a line.  Clearly you don't want to delete everything right of the line made by AB because then part of the vertical line would be cut off in the second image. What do you *actually* want to delete?  Are you expecting the algorithm to detect the right edge of the vertical line and delete everything right of that AND right of AB?  There's a decision to be made that you haven't given us the criteria for.

Comment: I want to delete the red pixels to the right of the line segment AB (so that the end result is the picture on the right). Using the algorithm provided [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630219/algorithm-to-find-the-coordinates-of-a-corner-in-a-simple-image) I will find the intersections A and B. From there, I would like to delete the extra red part. I agree that deleting everything outside of the line wouldn't work, so that's why I'm looking for a better algorithm.

Comment: Ok, so basically you want to delete a polygon where one edge is AB, and the rest are the result of tracing the edges that nub?  So that extra nub will never loop back on itself or stretch past the limit of the image?

Comment: Yes in most cases the picture will be pretty much like above. Different curves and slightly different sizes but overall it should be similar. This is basically a tool to assist the user in deleting this small nub in a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two points define a line. The equation of line separates pixels that have to be removed. If you want to delete points in a way that new border is smoothly following the curve of the shape you need some way to interpolate the shape border (based on the information of other points from the border). This interpolation have to pass trough two black points. Now, if you have interpolation you can calculate the interpolation curve between two black points and set to white all points right from the curve. I can suggest to use at least one more point from the curve and use some [cubic spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).

EDIT: 
Based on you comment.

Then the algorithm is simple: Keep a pointer that starts from lower point (A) and moves along the border (A') until it reaches the other point. This can be done by checking the neighbors of current pointer location and comparing colors. Now, when you pointer moves remove the line of red points from pointer (A') to line (blue) defined between to points A-B (in green). There is a pointer position when the row is the same as the other black point (e.g A' and B are on the same row). Then start a new pointer from B point in the same way tracing the border and remove the red pixels between two pointers A' and B'.

[image]

Comment: Actually the picture above was a zoom on one area. The whole picture is bigger and there might be more things, beside the nub, to the right of the line segment. The algorithm I'm looking for needs to detect the red pixels to the right of the line segments and stop erasing when reaching the white pixels. Also, to keep it simple, I'm fine with having the cut to be straight, it doesn't have to follow the curve nicely.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I ended up implementing a combination of your solution and Mark's and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw the line from A to B and then start a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) on one of the red pixels to the right of the line.